# HTML option tag for dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I need to be able to store and retrieve an additional ID when creating a dropdown list box.  Currently my option values are -

```
<option value="@x.Id" description="@x.Description" selected="selected">@x.PromotionCode</option>
```

and then I am able to retrieve the value using -

```
    $("#discount-selection").change(function () {
        alert ($(this).val())
    });
```

What other element in the option tag can I use and how do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you HTML5 data attributes to get anything you like from an element for example.

### HTML

```
<option value="@x.Id" data-description="@x.Description" data-index="0" selected="selected">@x.PromotionCode</option>
```

### JavaScript

```
$("#discount-selection").change(function ()
{
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected');

    selected.data('description'); // returns @x.Description
    selected.data('index'); // returns 0
});
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/8j7dq/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **data-*** introduced in HTML5 for storing custom data private to the page or application